# What are these sentences in English?

Tags: translation, meaning, vocabulary, meaning-in-context

I'm currently reading some Chinese novels to improve my reading ability. There are sentences that I can understand roughly but can not describe them in English. I would love to understand the sentence completely. Here they are:

1. "有点鸡冻! 传说中的备胎反击战?"
2. "作为交换, 我们可以卖你个人情让你成为他们公司的签约插画师"

I think there will be more, but for now that's it. Thanks for reading, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 有点鸡冻 find meaning by web search ：http://www.yhjdcom.com/jtqgyh/04-17-16/2916.html for rest use dictionaries

Comment: see comment #1:鸡冻  话题:鸡冻是什么意思？
答：原来是指鸡肉鸡汤凝成的冻。 也是激动的谐音。
话题:东北话鸡冻什么意思?
答： 不是东北话，是网络俗语，激动,  
translation attempt:    "有点鸡冻! 传说中的备胎反击战?" Some excitement! The legendary spare tire counter attack? In exchange, we can bestow the  favor of  making you become their company's contract illustrator. 
    "作为交换, 我们可以卖你个人情让你成为他们公司的签约插画师"

Answer (score 1):

有点鸡冻! I'm a little excited! (Should be '激动‘， they use 鸡冻 for fun.）

备胎, ‘spare tire' is a girl's nr. 2 bf, when nr. 1 doesn't bring it, although could be applied to a boy's nr. 2 gf.

反击战： strike back

传说中的备胎反击战? The legendary 'spare tire' strikes back? (Raises eyebrows questioningly)

What are your reading? Certainly ain't Chinese Literature, no peach blossoms by tinkling streams on mountaintops!

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! I understand the paragraph more clear now. Yes it isn't Chinese Literature, just some, 'love novel' my friend sent me, and since the characters are really cute, I decided to read it through, although there are a lot of slangs and weird words that young people use :DD